# Getting exception in HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthSTreamingMode()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set `fixedLengthStreamingMode()` property in `HttpURLConnection`object but getting an exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`
.

**Code:**

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            String url = this.fileParameter.getServerUrl();
            conn = getMultipartHttpURLConnection(url, boundary);
            String header=setRequestHeaders(conn);
            conn.setRequestProperty(this.fileParameter.getFileKey(),
                    this.fileParameter.getFileName());
            requestSize= (header.length()+new File(fileParameter.getFilePath()).length());
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(requestSize);
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17418): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()   

 E/AndroidRuntime(17418): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.net.HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode
```

**Note:** I am using java 7 platform .

Comment: `setFixedLengthStreamingMode` is available from API 19 on which version you are testing application?

Comment: My build target is 20 and i am running it in API 16. I didn't get any warning though.

Comment: There are two methods for setting Fixed Length Streaming Mode, one with  int argument is supported in api 16, which i am using.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int)

There are two methods:

- setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int) `Added in API level 1`
- setFixedLengthStreamingMode(long) `Added in API level 19`

`int` max value is 2,147,483,647

`long` max value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Streaming terms, this means that `setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int)` can have a maximum size length of (decimals removed for safety):

```
int sizeInBytes = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // 2,147,483,647 bytes
int sizeInKB = sizeInBytes / 1024;   // 2,097,151 kilobytes
int sizeInMB = sizeInKB / 1024;      // 2,047 megabytes
int sizeInGB = sizeInMB / 1024;      // 1.99 gigabytes
```

`setFixedLengthStreamingMode(long)` added in API 19 was to support larger sizes than what `Integer.Max` is capable of (ie. Large Files):

```
long sizeInBytes = Long.MAX_VALUE;  // 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes
long sizeInKB = sizeInBytes / 1024; // 9,007,119,254,740,991 kilobytes
long sizeInMB = sizeInKB / 1024;    // 8,796,014,897,207 megabytes
long sizeInGB = sizeInMB / 1024;    // 8,589,858,298 gigabytes
long sizeInTB = sizeInGB / 1024;    // 8,388,533 terabytes
long sizeInPB = sizeInTB / 1024;    // 8,191 petabytes
```

If you are never going to exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then cast your `long contentLength` to int and will not get the API error, however can get error when `requestSize > Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) requestSize);
```

You can simply do:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(requestSize);
} else if (requestSize <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) requestSize);
} else {
    //Don't set fixed length...
}
```